# Show Vector3 of a gameObject when enum is selected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to show in inspector the position of a gameObject when it is instantiated so that it can be altered?
I am selecting a gameObject (through enum) to be instantiated in the scene, how do I declare in inspector to show the positions in the script so that the user can freely change it after it has been instantiated?

```
public enum GOs {

        One,
        Two

    }
    public GOs go= GOs.Two;

 public void CreateGameObject () {

        if (go== GOs.One) {
            GameObject One_Prefab = UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath ("Resources/1.prefab", typeof (GameObject)) as GameObject;
            GameObject One = (GameObject) GameObject.Instantiate (One_Prefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
            One.name = One_Prefab.name;
            One.transform.parent = this.transform;
            One.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0); //declare this as public so that it can be changed by the user
            
        }
```

Comment: a bit unclear what your goal is. Couldn't you make that field `public Vector3 initPosition;` and then use this instead when assigning the position?

Answer (score 1):

If your main script handle the position of the instantiate gameObject you can do:
GameObject One;
Vector3 OnePosition;

```
private void Update()
{
    One.transform.position = OnePosition;
}
```

Don't forget to set the One gameobject:

```
public void CreateGameObject ()
{
    if (go== GOs.One) {
    GameObject One_Prefab = UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath ("Resources/1.prefab", typeof (GameObject)) as GameObject;
            
    One = (GameObject) GameObject.Instantiate (One_Prefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
    One.name = One_Prefab.name;
    One.transform.parent = this.transform;
    One.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0); //declare this as public so that it can be changed by the user       
}
```

If your script don't manipulate your instantiate gameobject you can find the new instantiate gameobject on your scene Hierarchy panel click on it and modify the transform position.

Another solution could be to create a custom inspector to handle a change on a Vector field and set the instantiate gameobject position when the field change. It remove the update position attribution. If this is what you want you can take a look to [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html).